# Xen: 'this operation could not be performed' (VDI is in use) error?

Tags: xen

How do I resolve the error:

```
This operation could not be performed because a VDI is in use by some other operation
```

I see this when trying to (re)start a stopped VM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(For Xen 6.2) If you have access to XenCenter go to 'view' 'show hidden' and make sure that there isn't a job running for this VM already. If there is, stop and delete it.

This may happen if you tried to export a VM and it didn't complete (for whatever reason).

Comment: erthbunny thank you. I ran into that same situation. Failed exports. I did have to use the Force Shutdown option to get to delete vm option. Thank You! JN

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer helped me. the only issue is that the hidden job was stating it was running on another vm - a vm not present in my environment, but shut down and than delete the "transfer vm" did the trick. i was able to power on the faulty vm afterwards